# How to use ngFor on a cdkDropList?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm trying to make a ticket board with Angular, where you can drag tickets into droplists to asign them to a certain person. However I'm having trouble with dynamically changing the amount of droplists, seeing as I want it to be connected to the amount of moderators on the board. Using ngFor makes it so the [cdkDropListConnectedTo] attribute fails to connect to the other droplist. Is there a way to fix this?

```
<main>
  <div class="open-tickets-container">
    <div class="ticket-list-container" cdk-scrollable>
      <h2>Open Tickets</h2>
      <div
        cdkDropList
        #openTickets="cdkDropList"
        [cdkDropListData]="open"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[manLane]"
        class="ticket-list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <app-ticket *ngFor="let item of open" [ticketName]="item" cdkDrag class="ticket"></app-ticket>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="board">
    <!---This is where I'd want the ngFor---> 
    <div class="ticket-list-container" cdk-scrollable>
      <h2>Naam</h2>
      <div
        cdkDropList
        #manLane="cdkDropList"
        [cdkDropListData]="assigned"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[openTickets]"
        class="ticket-list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <app-ticket *ngFor="let item of assigned" [ticketName]="item" cdkDrag class="ticket"></app-ticket>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: to connect severals cdkDropList, you can enclosed all of them in a div with `cdkDropListGroup`, see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can connect on ids in the form of strings as well! This does work

```
<main>
  <div class="open-tickets-container">
    <div class="ticket-list-container" cdk-scrollable>
      <h2>Open Tickets</h2>
      <div
        cdkDropList
        #openTickets="cdkDropList"
        [cdkDropListData]="open"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="managers"
        class="ticket-list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <app-ticket *ngFor="let item of open" [ticketName]="item" cdkDrag class="ticket"></app-ticket>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="board">
    <div *ngFor="let manager of managers" class="ticket-list-container" cdk-scrollable>
      <h2>{{manager}}</h2>
      <div
        cdkDropList
        id="{{manager}}"
        #manLane="cdkDropList"
        [cdkDropListData]="assigned"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[openTickets]"
        class="ticket-list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <app-ticket *ngFor="let item of assigned" [ticketName]="item" cdkDrag class="ticket"></app-ticket>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

The managers array is an array of strings in this case

Comment: use `cdkDropListGroup`